# Computing homology classes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Problem statement with diagram: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GLSEP919BMVwWckaJKsjb_Wi8TKVWMYj/view?usp=drivesdk

I'm completely stuck on exercise 2.15. I'm self studying a bit of topology during winter break and this is the first time I've had a problem like that and there are no example problem in the book.

The way the book defined homology on 2d spaces, two curves are homologous if and only if there is a surface connecting them. Algebraically, I believe that means there must be a continuous invertible function between them. Earlier, homology was defined as an equivalence relation and I'm good with that. So my understanding is that I need to find the equivalence class of paths in R³/(B ∪ C) that can all be "smoothly" transformed into A. But I don't have a clue how to do that. The book explained the idea of homology classes, but not how to specify a specific one, let alone how to do it for two different spaces. I've been Googling trying to find examples of how to specify/define homology classes, but I couldn't find any example problems. Can someone please help?

Comment: Based on your description, I feel like you're talking about something similar to non-trivial classes of the fundamental group. But it's not clear to me whether the text you referred to discusses the fundamental group before this exercise (probably not).

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: First, observe ${\mathbb R}^3/(B\cup C)$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of two $2$-spheres and two circles, i.e. glue the north poles of two $2$-spheres together, and then glue two circles to the north pole. Thus $H_1( {\mathbb R}^3/(B\cup C))={\mathbb Z}\oplus{\mathbb Z}$. Then see $A$ is the class $(0, 2)\in {\mathbb Z}\oplus{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: Sorry should be $(0, 0)\in {\mathbb Z}\oplus{\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @Yuval https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07YMPK3MT/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_prS8FbQXKN14K

Answer (score 1):

See that $A$ is homologous to the union of the two little red loops going around the blue circle. Then note the two little loops go around the blue circle in opposite directions, so they cancel to get the $0$ homology class.

[image: You]

Now $A$ (the red circle above left) minus the red cycle (the two little red loops above right) is the boundary of a surface that does not intersect $B, C$, as see below left; finally the two little red loops is trivial in homology since they together form the boundary of a cylinder that does not intersect $B, C$, see below right.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand.  What's the 0 homology class?  Is it the same as the fundamental group?

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese Homology group is differerent from fundamental group. The point is that the exercise in your textbook should be coherent to what is mentioned before the question, and that's what we're wondering, since it makes no sense for the author to ask a question relative to homology group before formally introduce the definition of homology group (resp. fundamental group). What Yuval is doing here is to show that $A$ is homologous to the trivial class.